# Junit 5 unit test case for static method with layerig

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I have a class name `LookupCode` which is written as below.

```
class LookupCode {
   public static LookUpCode getInstance() {
         // This part will have more code for singleton.
        return new LookUpCode();
  }
  public Map getCodeList(String code, String label) {
    // return map.
 }

}
```

My service class `ABCService` using `LookupCode` class of method `getCodeList()`.

```
class ABCService {
    LookupCode().getInstance().getCodeList("123", "456")`;
}
```

I wrote the test for `ABCService` by using `Junit5` and `Mockito`. I am getting the exceptions from `mockito` saying `getInstance() should return` LookupCode`.

```
@Test
void test() {
 try(MockedStatic<LookupCode> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStaticLookupCode.class)) {
  mockedStatic.when(() -> LookupCode().getInstance().getCodeList("123", "456")).thenReturn(buildMap());
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first mock the result of the static method call `.getInstance()` and return a mocked instance of your `LookukpCode` class. Next, provide the stubbing on this mocked instance:

```
@Test
void test() {

 LookupCode mockedLookupInstance = mock(LookupCode.class);

 try(MockedStatic<LookupCode> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(LookupCode.class)) {
  mockedStatic.when(LookupCode::getInstance).thenReturn(mockedLookupInstance);    
  when(mockedLookupInstance.getCodeList("123", "456").thenReturn(yourMap):
 }
}
```

Not sure if [deep stubbing](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.6.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) works for mocking static methods with Mockito.